# how to reference an external jar in jsp app?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jar

I am new to Eclipse. I am trying to run a jsp example using iText to generate a PDF, 
I put iText.jar file in Referense Library folder, but when I ran the jsp, I got error message that the class Document defined in the iText,jar can't not 
be resolved.

Comment: we dont actually add jars to reference library.. IDE creates the reference library lists.. all you have to do is add the jar in WEB-INF lib folder and add it to build path.. it will automatically added to reference libraries list. :-)

Answer (score 12):

1. Add the jar in WEB-INF/lib
2. add `<%@ page import="com.lowagie.itext.Document" %>` (or whatever the package is) to the top of your JSP

Comment: How should I include before deploying?

Answer (score 2):

You can also add this jar into the project lib folder(present in WEB-INF, if not present you can add a folder in WEB-INF).

Now you can either

> Right click on your project folder in
>   the navigator, choose properties,
>   choose java build path, select the
>   libraries tab, click **Add External Jars**..., choose your jar. Click OK.

or

> Right click on your project folder in
>   the navigator, choose properties,
>   choose java build path, select the
>   libraries tab, click **Add Jars**..., choose your jar. Click OK.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Right click on your project folder in the navigator, choose properties, choose java build path, select the libraries tab, click Add Jars, Jar Selection dialog shows up,click wenContent folder, the jar file does not show up. no way to add jar this way

Comment: okies... 

1st wat you have t o do is copy the jar file into WEB-INF/lib folder..

then try webContent/WEB-INF/lib
Then try adding as jar..

if this doesn work then try adding as ext jar file (after putting jar in webContet/WEB-INF/lib and pointig) to that file

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project folder in the navigator, choose properties, choose java build path, select the libraries tab, click Add External Jars..., choose your jar. Click OK.

Comment: Just what I did, the jar file shows in Referense Library folder. but the jsp can;t be compiled

Comment: @northTiger: How exactly are you compiling the jsp file? Usually the web container does that, not the IDE.

Comment: there is red underline in IDE under 
Document document = new Document();

Comment: and I got warning" 
"Classpath entry C:/workspace/intro/WebContent/iText-2.1.7.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result."

Comment: @northTiger: You may need to simply right-click refresh the project. See this link: http://www.coderanch.com/t/448061/IDEs-Version-Control-other-tools/Eclipse-project-Jar-will-not .