# Why won't my IDE recognize this type that I believe I have correctly imported in a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, rss, rome

This is driving me mad, and I've already sought previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719824/how-to-reference-an-external-jar-in-jsp-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package), to no avail so far.

I am trying to follow [this](http://cse.csusb.edu/turner/java_web_programming/news_feed_app/) tutorial, which uses the Rome library for RSS feeds to output feed entries to a JSP using a servlet. I'm using Eclipse, and it won't recognize a "SyndFeed" class from Rome, even though I have placed the JAR in the project's build path and the WEB-INF/lib folder. Still says "Undefined Type" for the following code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="syndFeed" scope="request" type="SyndFeed" />
```

Above this, I have:

```
<%@ page import="com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed" %> 
<%@ page import="com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
```

My servlet, using Rome, is basically straight from the tutorial:

```
public class RssServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private RequestDispatcher indexJSP;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
        indexJSP = context.getRequestDispatcher("/WebContent/index.jsp");
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        URL feedURL = new URL("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_tech.rss");
        SyndFeedInput syndInput = new SyndFeedInput();
        SyndFeed syndFeed = null;
        XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlReader( feedURL );

        try {
            syndFeed = syndInput.build( xmlReader );
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FeedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        request.setAttribute("syndFeed", syndFeed);
        indexJSP.forward(request, response);

    }


}
```

The servlet shows no compiling errors. All imports OK, including from `com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed`.

I'm at a loss. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Subin. Turned out I had the wrong attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class` and `type` attributes of `jsp:useBean` (these two attributes mean different things; make sure you are using the right one for your needs) expect the fully-qualified class name. Use:

```
<jsp:useBean id="syndFeed" scope="request" type="com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed" />
```

Comment: *Facepalm* Yup, that did it. For anyone else who might have this problem, note that SyndFeed is an interface, so once you change "type" to "class" you'll get a "cannot instantiate" error. But this does answer original question. Thank you, Issac!